# Invalidate / onDraw from static method Android

Tags: java, android, static-methods

I am working on Android project. I have ViewPage (activity) which have fragment PainterFragment. In PainterFragment method onCreateView I return Painter(getActivity());

In my Painter class I draw objects (onDraw). Now I need to refresh View. I have static method refresh (which I call from ViewPage) but it can't invalidate / run non static function, so my View only refresh when I tap it etc because onScale / onTouch.

What I should do to refresh View from Painter class? Maybe make programmatically onTouch event when I want to refresh it?

```
public class Painter extends View {


    private static final int INVALID_POINTER_ID = -1;
    ...
    static Context baseContext;

    public Painter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);     
        baseContext = getContext();

    }

    public Painter(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        baseContext = getContext();
        mScaleDetector = new ScaleGestureDetector(context, new ScaleListener());
    }

    private class ScaleListener extends ScaleGestureDetector.SimpleOnScaleGestureListener {


        @Override
        public boolean onScale(ScaleGestureDetector detector) {
            mScaleFactor *= detector.getScaleFactor();

            // Zabezpieczenie przed nieskończonym zoomowaniem
            mScaleFactor = Math.max(0.5f, Math.min(mScaleFactor, 10.0f));      
            invalidate();
            return true;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
        // Let the ScaleGestureDetector inspect all events.

        mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(ev);

        final int action = ev.getAction();
        switch (action & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            final float x = ev.getX();
            final float y = ev.getY();

            float px = ev.getX() / mScaleFactor + myRect.left;
            float py = ev.getY() / mScaleFactor + myRect.top;

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;
            mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(0);
            for(int i = 0; i<listPointer.size(); i++) {
                ...
            }
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {
            final int pointerIndex = ev.findPointerIndex(mActivePointerId);
            final float x = ev.getX(pointerIndex);
            final float y = ev.getY(pointerIndex);

            // Only move if the ScaleGestureDetector isn't processing a gesture.
            if (!mScaleDetector.isInProgress()) {
                final float dx = x - mLastTouchX;
                final float dy = y - mLastTouchY;

                mPosX += dx;
                mPosY += dy;

                invalidate();
            }

            mLastTouchX = x;
            mLastTouchY = y;

            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL: {
            mActivePointerId = INVALID_POINTER_ID;
            break;
        }

        case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP: {
            final int pointerIndex = (ev.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_MASK) 
                    >> MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_INDEX_SHIFT;
            final int pointerId = ev.getPointerId(pointerIndex);
            if (pointerId == mActivePointerId) {

                final int newPointerIndex = pointerIndex == 0 ? 1 : 0;
                mLastTouchX = ev.getX(newPointerIndex);
                mLastTouchY = ev.getY(newPointerIndex);
                mActivePointerId = ev.getPointerId(newPointerIndex);
            }
            break;
        }
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Painter(Context context) {

        this(context, null, 0);
        baseContext = getContext();
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        refresher();

    }

    public void refresher() {

        if(printTable != null) printTable.clear();

        if(listOrders!=null & baseContext!=null) listOrders = Bridge.getOrders(baseContext);

        if(listTable!=null) {
            for(Table table: listTable) {

            printTable.add(table);
            }

        }

        invalidate();

    }
    public static void refresh() {

        if(printTable != null) printTable.clear();

        if(listOrders!=null & baseContext!=null) listOrders = Bridge.getOrders(baseContext);

        if(listTable!=null) {
            for(Table table: listTable) {

            printTable.add(table);
            }

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {

        super.onDraw(canvas);
        ...   
    }

    public void Draw(Table item, Canvas canvas)
    {
        ...     
    }    
    }



}
```

Comment: What code are you using to access this method? This is definitely a bad design choice, and answerers might instead be able to help you fix this decision.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why cant you take the view to a variable like

View myView= Painter.this();
myView.invalidate(); inside the painter class.